# Typescript error on computed array property: "Property 'map' does not exist on type 'ComputedRef<any>"

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a computed property (array) which is taken from another computed property.

When trying to use `map/filter/reduce/find` on the property, it causes the linting error:

```
Property 'map' does not exist on type 'ComputedRef<any>
```

So how do I declare that computed property in the correct way?
I'm using Vue 3 (composition api) with Typescript and Volar (for vscode).

```
const product = reactive({});            //<-- empty until it is loaded

const getItem = computed(() => {
  return items.map( (item:any) => {      //<-- typescript error
    return item;                   //(simplified code, returns 1 item in reality)
})

const items = computed(() => {
  return product?.items;                //<-- items array        
});
```

I also  tried

```
const items = computed<any[]>(() => {
```

which causes the same error (on getItem function).

And this:

```
const items:any[] = computed<any[]>(() => {
```

which causes error on "items" that says `Type 'ComputedRef<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop`(..etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Computed refs](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#computed) have a `value` prop that allow you to access the ref's, well, value.

So you would actually use it like this:

```
const product = reactive({});

const getItem = computed(() => {
  return items.value.map((item:any) => {
    return item;
  });
});

const items = computed(() => {
  return product?.items;     
});
```

Comment: That does work, but I thought I didn't need it when using "reactive"?
This code works without using "value":
const test1 = reactive({
    myProp: 'okay'
});
const getProp = computed(() => test1.myProp);
So do I have to use ".value" if accessing an array or something that is not a primitive value?

Comment: @Galivan Sorry, I meant to say "computed refs". Only computed refs seem to require the `value` prop.

Comment: But why does the code snippet work then? (adding ".value" to that snippet causes error)
Is it because the computed property was referencing a computed property?
I can add the snippet to the question

Comment: @Galivan You aren't using the computed ref `getProp`, you're using the reactive value `test1`.

Comment: Okay great, I got it now , thanks!